# Why do we take 2 derivatives of the right side of a heterogeneous ODE when using the method of undetermined coefficients?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let g(x) be the right side of a heterogeneous ODE. Why do we take 2 derivatives of g(x) when using the method of undetermined coefficients? g(x), g'(x), and g''(x) is used to guess the form of the particular solution.

The textbook says to assume the particular solutions includes g(x), g'(x), and g''(x) but doesn't answer why.

[image]

Also, to expand further, the textbook says if the terms of a particular solution are already in the complementary solution, to multiply the particular solution by x, but I don't understand why we do that.

Comment: For both $\sin$ and $\cos$, taking two derivatives gets back to the negative of the original function (plus coefficients).  Two derivatives helps identify the type of cycle of cyclic derivative functions.

Comment: @abiessu: What if the function needed 10 derivatives to get back to the original function? What if successive derivatives never took you back to the original function? I still don't understand why we're even taking derivatives.

Comment: Because you're looking at a *second*-order differential equation!

Comment: @TedShifrin: So for a third-order differential equation, I would take 3 derivatives? Even if it takes 10 derivatives for it go back to the original function?

Comment: You might never get back to the original. But you have to plug your linear combination into the LHS of the equation, so you need as many derivatives as you'll need to substitute.

Comment: @TedShifrin: "But you have to plug your linear combination into the LHS of the equation, so you need as many derivatives as you'll need to substitute." Thanks. That answers my question perfectly.

Comment: What a horrible book.